Satmar shechita
I was told that the Satmar method of slaughtering is a method unto itself.
Can someone explain Satmar shechita and/or the differences by which it differentiates itself?

Simla chadasha is an important guide for satmar shochtim

@Dude Satmar or Ashkenazim in general?

I don't know about ashkenazim in general. I only know the satmar shochtim I work with learn it regularly

I know that Chabad don't eat satmar shechita

https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/general/77155/satmar-rebbe-speaks-out-against-ashkenazic-shechita-practice.html
